# Copying NSView using archivedDataWithRootObject / unarchiveObjectWithData

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to copy NSView and then add it to the same superview. I've found some code on Stackoverflow that uses archivedDataWithRootObject/unarchiveObjectWithData approach, but I am still missing something as the unarchived NSView doesn't show when added with an addSubview.

[image]

Here is the setup in Interface Builder. There is NSView with a referencing outlet in the ViewController named customView. It has two NSView subviews. I set their identities as "one" and "two. And extended NSView class so they could be found via identity. I am trying to copy the second NSView and then add it to the same parent NSView, but it doesn't appear.

Here is the code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
  @IBOutlet var customView: NSView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let v = customView.viewWithID("two")

    // create an NSData object from myView
    let archive = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(v!)

    // create a clone by unarchiving the NSData
    let myViewCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archive) as! NSView

    // I am setting the background color to make it visible
    myViewCopy.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor()

    // adding it
    customView.addSubview(myViewCopy)
    // .. and nothing happens!
    // so I tried to specify origin, to make sure it's not outside the visible area
    myViewCopy.frame.origin.x = 0
    myViewCopy.frame.origin.y = 0
    // .. still no effect
  }
}

extension NSView {
var backgroundColor: NSColor? {
    get {
        if let colorRef = self.layer?.backgroundColor {
            return NSColor(CGColor: colorRef)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    set {
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = newValue?.CGColor
    }
}

func viewWithID(id:String) -> NSView? {
    for view in subviews {
        if let identifier = view.identifier {
            if identifier == id {
                return view
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add the implementation of NSCoding for that view.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? By implement you mean just to call super?

Comment: You did not implement that? So, do you expect to write and read some data to initialize it correctly? What is the type (class) of that view? However, copying views is no good technique. You should load it from nib repeatedly.

Comment: The class is NSView a "custom view" the way it is called in Interface Builder.

Comment: Amin, what I am trying to accomplish is to design a custom view with subviews in interface builder once, then "clone" it and populate in multiple places by adding as subviews and setting the origins.

Comment: Okay, being a `NSView` cloning that way should work. However, having a view hierarchy designed in IB, there is no need to copy it. Simply put it in a separate nib and load that nib repeatedly using `-loadNibNamed:owner:options:` (`NSBundle`)  et al.

Comment: It should work, but it doesn't the "cloned" NSView doesn't show up and I can't figure out whats missing.. regarding your other idea - so I can't just use storyboard and keep everything there without creating a separate nib file?

Comment: You should use a separate nib file for this. This is a well-known and proofed concept. (Maybe your solution does not work, because theold and new view are on the same position. It is hard to know what goes wrong with that snippet. At least you should print-out both views and add the log to your Q.)

Comment: NSLog doesn't print out much for NSView.. so I added the screenshot which shows original and "clone" frame property. I moved clone's origin to 0,0, so they don't clip I also tried removing the original view completely out of the way with removeFromSuperview() which didn't help. I understand that I could use the nib, but I wanted to implement it all within a storyboard, without resorting to legacy..

Comment: resorting to legacy? Well, copying views by serialization is one of the oldest dirty hacks around in OS X.

Comment: What do you expect an instance of `NSView` to display?

Comment: I added NSLog("%@", v!) and NSLog("%@", myViewCopy) as you said "you should print out both view", but it didn't print anything helpful, just a class name and a memory address. I am totally stuck now.. the view seems to be copied but not displayed when I add it.. what else can I try without resorting to nib?

Comment: You can use `NSStringFromRect()` et al. However, the screen shot from debugger is okay. Did you read my last Q?

Comment: "What do you expect an instance of NSView to display?" -- for now just as POC to display a colored rectangle, so I set its background color.

Comment: any other information I could provide?